# Google Contacts API - Invisible shared domain contact

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-contacts-api, google-shared-contacts

I'm trying to create shared contact with google contacts api v3.

Now i'm in situation, when i logged in with service account to company domain (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/domain.ltd/full).

I successfully create new account. But this account is not shared. Contact is visible only for this service account.

Is there some switch to activate shared contacts? If i created contact in default domain, so contact is visible for account user. But in company domain not.

I will be happy for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know the problem without seeing code but I suspect your service account is not impersonating an admin in the domain and thus the contacts you are creating are specific to the service account, not your Google domain.